# Get request hanging in grinder

Tags: grinder

When I am starting the grinder to load test a simple Web Application nothing happens and it goes to hang .
I had previously run the same scripts on different machine and it used to work.I tried to debug it by putting print statements and saw that print after GET was not coming.
Any help or suggestion welcomed ..

Comment: Can you post the script you are trying to run so people can better help you figure out the issue?

Comment: @tweray                                                          <code>from net.grinder.script.Grinder import grinder
from net.grinder.script import Test
from net.grinder.plugin.http import HTTPRequest
 
test1 = Test(1, "Request resource")
print "hello 1"
request1 = HTTPRequest()
print "hello 2" 
test1.record(request1)
 
class TestRunner:
    def __call__(self):
        result = request1.GET("http://23:8080/")
        print "hello 3"
        # result is a HTTPClient.HTTPResult. We get the message body
        # using the getText() method. </code>

Comment: grinder.script = test.py
grinder.processes = 1
grinder.threads = 1
grinder.runs = 1

Comment: Please edit your origin post and put the formatted code there.

Comment: @tweray Any of the code samples listed on grinder website are hanging .It simply says starting Threads and does nothing while same thing works on other machine.Any idea or any pointers I may try ...

Answer (score 0):

Well this came out to be a system issue since same setup is working on a different machine. However I figured out that by running grinder in grinder.debug.singleprocess mode and setting up  -javaagent:path/grinder-dcr-agent-version.jar works on the same machine . This is strange for me as well .Hope that helps.